# IE9 ASP.net Session ID changes when reloads all Tabs click several times

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I m stuck in a strange issue,
Environment : I m using Asp.net State Server for Storing session, and My Session Time out is 20 Minutes
My Scenario is that, I am updating ASP.NET_SessionId  cookies from Java Script on every time page reloads like this

```
 var n = 'ASP.NET_SessionId'         // cookie name
        var v = app.cookies.get(n)          // cookie value
        var d = '.abc.com'      // base domain to create domain level cookie
        var e = 0.1666666666668             // 4 hrs
        app.cookies.set(n, v, e, d)  // my method to update cookies
```

Now the problem is that, when I open that page in IE in multiple tabs like 8 or more tabs, end when I click refresh All Tabs (right click on any tab will bring this option) then doing this continuously will end in Session Expired  Message.

In session tracing I found that my session id is changed. And when I removed this logic of updating session id then it works fine.It is only happening in IE and not on Crome or firefox.

My Questions are
Why session id is changed?
Does JS lock that cookie  when updating its time and in same case other tabs request of updating result in crash and IE send new session Id to server.?

Comment: whwy do you need to do that in javascript?